# Animation for content is not working when adding UIViewController with content with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, autolayout, core-animation

I have a UIViewController which I am adding as subview in my iPad app. The UIViewcontroller has a UITableView which is resized as per autolayout set in storyboard. I want to show animation of moving this view from center to right end of iPad(Landscape mode). For this I am setting width initially 0 and increasing it in animation block. Although the animation works good the tableview inside the UIViewController is added before animation. So it doesn't animate. IT should also expand with its parent(UIViewController). My code:

```
@IBAction func tappedNotifications(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Content_iPad", bundle: nil)
    let notificationSettingsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SettingsViewController_iPad")
    notificationSettingsVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 380, y: 0, width: 0, height: 775)
    self.view.addSubview(notificationSettingsVC.view)
    notificationSettingsVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
        notificationSettingsVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 380, y: 0, width: 0, height: 775)
        notificationSettingsVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 380, y: 0, width: 570, height: 775)
        notificationSettingsVC.view.setNeedsLayout()
    }, completion: {
        (completed) -> Void in

    })
}
```

Comment: perform animatio on notificationSettingsVC controller on viewwillappear() method its working fine

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are telling your notification view controller to animate its width to 0 and 570 both inside your animation block, try removing to frame change that sets the width to 0.

```
@IBAction func tappedNotifications(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Content_iPad", bundle: nil)
    let notificationSettingsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SettingsViewController_iPad")
    notificationSettingsVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 380, y: 0, width: 0, height: 775)
    self.view.addSubview(notificationSettingsVC.view)
    notificationSettingsVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
        notificationSettingsVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 380, y: 0, width: 570, height: 775)
        notificationSettingsVC.view.setNeedsLayout()
    }, completion: {
        (completed) -> Void in

    })
}
```

Comment: It is still not working, I believe the problem is because I have used view from storyboard and not created by coding

Comment: Could you provide some more information on how your view controller is setup in your storyboard, like the constraints being used on the table view inside your view controller etc